# To prove the expression is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, integers

It is required to prove that for positive integers $a$,$b$ if $$1+ab|a^2+b^2$$
then the integer

$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{1+ab}$$

is a perfect square. The proof is easily beyond me as I have only recently started studying number theory or maybe I'm not intelligent enough. Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Google for Vieta jumping

Comment: a directly proof appear recently...

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250172/when-is-fa-b-fraca2b21ab-a-perfect-square-rational-number/250187#250187

Comment: is this question 6?